# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

[Moderator election #1](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Martial Arts has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are... the same team you've already had!

[image: mattm]

[image: JohnP]

[image: slugster]

Please thank them for volunteering and congratulate them for being re-elected as moderators!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5114402979184640).

Comment: Congrats to all the winners! :)

Comment: Indeed. :-P Glad I could throw my hat in the ring. Maybe next time.

Answer (score 4):

On behalf of myself, Matt and John*:
thanks to the wider Community for that, you've reinvested us with a responsibility that we value and take seriously.

Also thanks to Macaco and Noufal, while you missed out this election you still gave the voters some excellent options.

*I didn't check with Matt and John before writing this, but I'm sure they'd agree :)

Comment: Heartily agreed :)

Comment: Nope. Ok, yeah, I agree :p. Thank you to everyone that voted and we appreciate your faith.

Comment: Yep. Thanks Macaco and Noufal, and well done to the winners. Everyone answered the election questions well. We're lucky to have a surplus of good candidates. All the best.